# Python returns ints when one of variable inside function is active

Tags: python, loops

The main idea is:
searchindex() - repeat binary search algorithm over the list of random data with looking back and with fix.(variable `counter1` should save number of occurences)
occur() - just assumning total number of occurences.
Please help to find a problem.

I always get counter1 = 0 after running a code.

```
def searchindex(searchlist, secs, x):
    ts = calendar.timegm(time.gmtime())
    delta_minute_ts = (ts - (ts % 60)) - secs
    last_minute = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(delta_minute_ts).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
    start = 0
    end = len(searchlist) - 1
    counter1 = 0
    while (start <= end):
        mid = (start + end) // 2
        if (searchlist[mid] == last_minute):
           counter1 = int(mid)
           if x == 1:
                end = mid - 1
           else:
                start = mid + 1
        elif (last_minute < searchlist[mid]):
            end = mid - 1
        else:
            start = mid + 1
    return counter1


def occur():
    start_result = searchindex(new1, 60, 1)
    end_result = searchindex(new1, 60, 2)
    if start_result is None:
       return 'no results'
    else:
       end_result - start_result + 1
```

Comment: The comparison `searchlist[mid] == last_minute` might not succeed since the `last_minute` is randomly generated. And it need not be in the `searchlist` you are passing.Hence the result 0. Try passing deterministic values to make sure the algorithm is working.

Comment: And if you just want to get the count of an element from a list in python, you can use `count()` method on lists. `[1,2,3,1].count(1)` will give you `2` as the result.

Comment: The feature is to use binary search algorith for sorted list, to find all the occurences plus counting them. You was right, the problem was hiding in type of `last_minute`, changing to usual timestamp was an answer. Thank you!